# $gcd(i,n)=1 \iff n\nmid ik$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working on my homework and have come into a problem. I am relying on this fact to prove the statement:

"Let $a$ have order $n$ modulo $m$ and let $i$  denote an integer. Prove that $a^i$ has order $n$ modulo $m$
if and only if $gcd(i, n)=1$.

My intuition keeps telling me to use the division algorithm, but I can't see it.

Hints appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to show that if the order of $a^i$ is $n$, then $\gcd(i,n)=1$. We see this since $(a^i)^{n/\gcd(i,n)}=1$.

For the other direction, we want to show that $\gcd(i,n)=1$ implies that the order of $a^i$ is $n$. Consider the contrapositive: show instead that if $a^i$ has an order different from $n$, then $\gcd(i,n)\neq1$.

Assume $a^i$ has an order $k\neq n$. Then $k$ must be a divisor of $n$ (as $(a^i)^n$ is still $1$). Also, we know that $ik$ is some multiple of $n$, which is to say, there is an integer $a$ such that $ik=an$. This gives
$$
i=a\frac nk
$$
Thus $\frac nk>1$ is a common divisor of $n$ and $i$.

Comment: There isn't much work left if you want to prove that the order of $a^i$ is exactly $\frac n{\gcd(i,n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

let $(i,n)=k$ where $k>1$

Then $n|i\cdot \frac{n}{k}$ because $\frac ik$ is an integer.

The other direction: assume $(n,i)=1$ and $n|ik$. Then there exists $m$ such that $ik-mn=1$ since $n,i$ coprime. $n|ik-mn=1$ which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Any hint on the other direction?

Comment: @Jungleshrimp see my edit.

Comment: What is $k$ defined as in your "other direction" proof?

Comment: Some $1\le k\le n-1$

Comment: In if gcd(n,i)=1, then there exists x and y such that nx+iy=1. The other assumption gives that for some t, nt=ik. How do I get to ik-mn=1?

Comment: @Jungleshrimp is there anything unclear in my proof?

Comment: How do you get that there exists m such that ik-mn=1?

Comment: @Jungleshrimp This is called Bezout's lemma.

Comment: @abc... What confused me, and possibly Jungleshrimp as well, is that you picked $k$ first, and then tried to claim it was a coefficient from Bezouts afterwards. This is not the case, and could be made clearer.

Comment: Well if $k>n$ then $k'=k-n, m'=m-i$ also works. Similarly we can treat the case $k\le 0$.

Comment: The size of $k$ is not the issue. The claim that $n\mid ik$, before trying to use Bezout's to find $k$ in the first place, is the issue.